# Powershell Testing connection speed

Tags: windows, powershell

Im trying to write a script in which i have for example

```
$var1 = '192.168.10.10'
$var2 = '192.168.10.20'
```

Id like to somehow test the ping speed from the user computer which runs the script and have him use the fastesr link.
How can i achive that?

Edit
I guess i can use

```
$test = ping $var1
```

And then get a string arrray which i can strip down and find 'time=...'
but im sure theres a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, Test-connection and use ResponseTime property

Answer (score -2):

The ping.exe function is far faster than Test-Connection as far as I can tell. Test-Connection is way too slow for the simple yes/no answers I typically need.

If you just need to see if something is present from powershell, ping.exe /n 1 /w 100 will timeout after 100 ms and only send 1 ping.

Select-String and the pipe create a string that says 'Request timed out' if the ping is not returned/host not found. -not casts the result as a bool: false if no connection, true if connection found.

This is the code I use to ping industrial machines quickly, where xxx is my target NIC's last octet:

```
$host_present = -not (ping 192.168.1.xxx /n 1 /w 100 | select-string -pattern 'Request timed out')
```